# Spring Boot- Fail to retrieve application.yml variable value using @Value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

I am trying to retrieve my base_url that is stored in the application.yml from my @RestController. However, when I use the code printed below, it always return null. Can someone please let me know why @Value("${base_url}") always return null? Thanks in advance.

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @Value("${company.department.base_url}")
    static String base_url;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getAccount")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAccount() {
        //getAccountCode
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
company:
  department:
    base_url: https://www.test.com
```

TestApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use static field, then you should do this:

```
@Value("${company.department.base_url}")
String base_url;
```

Or try a workaround for that:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think @Value can be used for static fields. One workaround is to use a non-static setter-based injection to set this.

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {


    static String base_url;

    @Value("${company.department.base_url}")
    public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl){
        this.base_url = baseUrl
    }
 }
```

Ref: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-inject-a-value-into-static-variables/